# When does a sum of squares uniquely define a pair of integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Given two positive integers $x,y$ ( $x \ne y$) the map $z=f(x,y)=x+y$ is many-to-one function. Given $z$, there are multiple of pairs that map under $f$ to the same image $z$. I'm interested in the map $z=g(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)$ and the conditions that make map $g$ one-to-one mapping (injection).

> When does a sum of squares uniquely define a pair of integers?

Update: A reformulation is the following algorithmic problem:

Input: Given $z$ that is a sum of two squares,

Query: Are there two pairs $(x,y)$, $(a,b)$ such that $z=a^2+b^2=x^2+y^2$?

It would be interesting if there exist an efficient algorithm for this algorithmic problem.

Note that $x,y,a,b$ are all distinct positive integers.

Comment: $1^2 + 7^2 = 5^2 + 5^2 = 50$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig $x \ne y$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig x and y are positive integers

Comment: The smallest counterexample I have in mind is $$10^2+15^2=17^2+6^2$$ https://wstein.org/edu/124/lectures/lecture21/lecture21/node2.html might be very relevant.

Comment: You may want to look up [Gaussian integers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer), paying attention to primes and factorization in this domain.

Comment: Also, $85^2 = 13^2 + 84^2 = 77^2 + 36^2$.

Comment: Smallest nonunique xase is $65=5×13=8^2+1^2=7^2+4^2$.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a function which isn’t injective, it’s usually meaningless to ask generically for “conditions” that make it injective. Conditions on what?

In this case, the map $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is not injective. It is finite-to-one, meaning the inverse image of any number in its range is at least finite, though it’s usually not a singleton.

One special case you may be interested in is that a *prime* number $p$ which is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ can be represented as a sum of squares in exactly one way, ignoring order. For example, $f(2,3)=f(3,2)=13$ are the only two solutions of $f(x,y)=13$. Other primes cannot be represented as a sum of squares at all.

So you may let $Q\subseteq \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ be the set of pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x\le y$ and $f(x,y)$ is prime. The function $f$ restricted to $Q$ is injective.

Note, however, that $Q$ is not maximal in that sense. There are larger sets that would work, but it’s not clear if this is what you’re searching for.

===

UPDATE: the question now asks for conditions under which a number is a sum of two squares in two distinct ways. This happens precisely when the prime factorization of the number contains two prime factors (not necessarily distinct) congruent to 1 mod 4.

The smallest such number is $25=5\times 5$ and indeed $25=0^2+5^2=3^2+4^2$. On the other hand, the numbers $10$ or $34$ do not possess two such factors yet they are still sums of squares, so they are sums of squares in a unique way.

See, for example, [here](http://users.rowan.edu/~hassen/Papers/SUM%20OF%20TWO%20SQUARES%20IN%20MORE%20THAN%20ONE%20WAY.pdf).

Comment: $f$ is also injective if $f(x,y)=p^2$, provided $0 \notin \mathbb N$.

Comment: Yup. And further variations are possible.

Comment: see the update.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany see my updated answer.

Comment: So, the problem is intractable since it is as hard as Integer factoring problem. Right?

Comment: I didn’t say it’s as hard as factorization, and I don’t know if it is. It’s certainly not *harder* than factorization.